# html:form when migrating to Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

My struts1 application is using this form declaration in jsp.

```
    <tiles:useAttribute name="formAction"/>
    <bean:define id="formAction" name="formAction" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <html:form method="POST" styleId="formAction">
```

How do I migrate this to struts2 without many changes? I tried supplying action to this form, in the last line above, using s:url tag, but it doesn't work. I think, I am going fundamentally wrong somewhere. Any advice please? Note that I don't want to use the new s tags as it will require a lo of efforts.

Comment: How will you use the old S1 tags if you're not planning on migrating?!

Comment: Struts2 is fundamentally different, and if you  don't want to migrate the jsp to the new s tags due to business constraints, don't ask this.

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that the new s tags are better, but one can still use html/jstl with struts2 with minimal changes like providing the action via s:url tag. Is that not correct? According to Roman, it looks like one has to compulsorily use s tags, is that the case?

Comment: You can use jstl with S2, but not old S1 tags.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `html` tags, you can use `Struts2 form tags`,

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<tiles:useAttribute name="formAction" var="formAction" />
<s:form action="%{formAction}" method="post">
....
</s:form>
```

Not tested, but if `%{formAction}` does not work use `${formAction}`, one of them will be working.